# NativeScript Error: Failed to install: could not transfer application to device

Tags: ios, nativescript, sidekick

suddenly my iOS App (NativeScript 5.1 Sidekick iOS Cloud build) does not get deployed on my device any more. The error message is not really helpful. Connectivity with the device is there... was working fine before. Host is Windows 10. Rebooting Pad and PC did not help.

> Error detected during LiveSync on xxxxxxxxxxxxxx for C:\app\testapp.
>   Error: Failed to install C:\app\testapp.cloud\ios\device\testapp.ipa
>   on device with identifier xxxxxxxxxxxx. Error is: **Could not transfer
>   application**

Google isn't really helpful on that problem either... any clues?